# Must I register if I am not required to have a visa for entering Russia?

Tags: visas, regulations, russia, emergencies, registration

I am an Argentinean citizen who arrived in Russia three weeks ago. At Moscow my passport was stamped and I was given a migratory card:

[image: Migration card]

I have read that tourists must register once they enter Russian territory but The Russian Federation does not require visas for Argentines, so **am I required to register if I don't have (nor need) a visa?**

If I am, and considering it's been a lot more than seven days since I entered, what would you recommend me to do?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @pnuts. Is there anywhere I can confirm this?

Comment: And I seriously appreciate it, @pnuts! So far, the only official document I've found is [Migration registration of foreign citizens in the Russian Federation](http://www.fms.gov.ru/government_services/migrate/index_eng.php) however it mentions hotels, but I'm using AirBnB. Hopefully, someone else will answer.

Thanks!

Comment: I answered a similar question some time ago [here](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/38204/how-to-register-russian-tourist-visa-while-on-the-trans-mongolian-railway/38372#38372). Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a difference between a visa and registration in Russia. Visa provides the permission to enter the Russia, but the registration provides information about you and your route to the police. [This practice comes from long time ago](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propiska_in_the_Soviet_Union), and all the people in Russia must be registered somethere, [including Russians themselves](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resident_registration_in_Russia).

More about the migration control for foreigners can be found here (English version at the bottom):

- [Миграционный учёт](http://www.ufms.spb.ru/desc/migracionnyj-uchjot-dind-723.html)
- [О порядке осуществления миграционного учета иностранных граждан и лиц без гражданства в Российской Федерации](http://www.fms.gov.ru/documentation/862/details/50477/2/)

According the [Federal law #109-FZ](http://www.fms.gov.ru/documentation/860/details/37042/4/):

> 2. Постановке на учет по месту пребывания подлежат:
>
> (в ред. Федерального закона от 19.07.2009 N 199-ФЗ)
>
> 1) постоянно проживающий в Российской Федерации иностранный гражданин
>   - по истечении семи рабочих дней со дня прибытия в место пребывания, **за исключением** случаев, когда указанный иностранный гражданин:
>
> ...
>
> б) **находится в гостинице или в иной организации, оказывающей
>   гостиничные услуги**, в санатории, доме отдыха, пансионате, кемпинге, на
>   туристской базе, в детском оздоровительном лагере, больнице либо в
>   ином учреждении здравоохранения или социального обслуживания;
>
> ...
>
> 2) временно проживающий или временно пребывающий в Российской
>   Федерации иностранный гражданин - по истечении семи рабочих дней со
>   дня прибытия в место пребывания, за исключением случаев, когда
>   указанный иностранный гражданин:
>
> (в ред. Федерального закона от 20.03.2011 N 42-ФЗ)
>
> а) **находится в гостинице или в иной организации, оказывающей
>   гостиничные услуги**, в санатории, доме отдыха, пансионате, кемпинге, на
>   туристской базе, в детском оздоровительном лагере, больнице либо в
>   ином учреждении здравоохранения или социального обслуживания;

All that stuff says that, if you arrive into Russia and stay **only** in hotels or similar places, you don't need to be registered. But if you arrive for your friends and stay in their flat, **they** should register you, and you need to get a stamp into your migration card.

So I suggest you to check the documents for your AirBnb owner, does he have a right to run the hotel, and if he do, you don't have to do anything, otherwise **he** should register you to avoid the fee.

Update, [English version](http://www.mid.ru/bul_ns_en.nsf/kartaflat/en08.01):

> Persons subject to registration at the place of stay: 1) a foreign
>   national constantly resident in the Russian Federation – after seven
>   working days from his/her arrival at the place of stay, except, when
>   that foreign national:
>
> ...
>
> b) is in a hotel or in some other organisation providing hotel
>   services, in a spa resort, health resort, recreation centre, camping,
>   travel camp, children’s holiday camp, medical organisation providing
>   medical aid in hospital conditions or a social service organisation;
>
> ...
>
> 2) a foreign national temporarily resident or temporarily staying in
>   the Russian Federation – after seven working days from his/her arrival
>   at the place of stay, except, when that foreign national:
>   a) is in a hotel or in some other organisation providing hotel services, in a spa
>   resort, health resort, recreation centre, camping, travel camp,
>   children’s holiday camp, medical organisation providing medical aid in
>   hospital conditions or a social service organisation;

Comment: Could you please replace "try the Google Translate for Russian, can't find the English version" wording with something like "English version at the bottom"?

Comment: Yep, forgot it :)

Comment: Extremely clear answer, @VMAtm. Since I have been staying on AirBnB apartments for more than 7 business day without registration, can I be registered by a travel agency now or is it too late? Thanks!

Comment: Again, `All that stuff says that, if you arrive into Russia and stay only in hotels or similar places, you don't need to be registered.` - the hotel, if it has a license, already registered you. If it doesn't, you can do it by yourself and there is no bad for you as you aren't the person who must do it.

Comment: @JuanIgnacioIglesias Try to contact your Embassy or Consulate, and get the information from there.

Answer (score 6):

Hello @JuanIgnacioIglesias and welcome to Russia.

You should be registered in Moscow, if you'll stay there more than 7 days. It doesn't depends do you require visa or not. Registration in Moscow is obligatory for all foreign people.

If you stay with AirBnb, ask your homeowner to make the registration for you. All information about registration procedure can be found here http://www.fmsmoscow.ru/docs/migration_registration/registration.html

This procedure is very simple, can be done in any post office and will not take more than 15 minutes.

Comment: Hello @MikkaRin, thanks for answering. My first AirBnB host said it wasn't necessary for me to register but it turns out it is, more than 7 days have passed now. I called a tourist embassy in SPb and they said they can register me, even after the 7 days period for 2600 rubbles. Is this a normal procedure?

Comment: That's very expensive. Usually this procedure cost around 200 roubles. Talk with your Host again and ask to register you with using newer date, for example, since yesterday. You will need this registration only if police man stops you on the street and checks your documents. They will not check dates of your arrival in a country, just a fact that you already registered. Anyway, if they will have questions - just lie them. You may tell that spend a week to travel in St. Petersburg and that's why your didn't register before. When you will move out from Russia you will need only migration card.

Comment: I asked my host but he refused to register me. If the price isn't a problem, would you recommend using the tourist agency service? Thanks!

Comment: They can probably register you like staying in the hotel. Just check that they'll give you back documents like on those pictures http://kdpconsulting.ru/obrazcy-dokumentov/807-obrazec-dokumentov-prodlennogo-migracionnogo-ucheta.html